# WPF: 2 string.format in the same TextBlock?

Tags: wpf, geometry, shapes, textblock, string.format

I have a `Circle slider` and inside this `Slider` i put `TextBlock` that shows the `Slider` value, I also use `String.Format` to present the value in `int` instead of `double`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=knobSlider, StringFormat={}{0:#,#}}" Foreground="White"
           FontFamily="Trebuchet MS" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Now want to add before the `Slider` value a specific character for example `'*'`, so is it possible to user another `string.format` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for another StringFormat - if you're trying to add characters *before* the value, you just need to replace the double curly braces with your text. I think this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="Trebuchet MS"
        FontSize="25"
        Foreground="White"
        Text="{Binding Path=Value,
                        ElementName=knobSlider,
                        StringFormat=\*{0:#,#}}" />
```